# Can GridGain 6 handle a task with many jobs

Tags: gridgain

I'm investigating improvements in the new GridGain release and wanted to know how GridGain 6 handles tasks with many jobs.

Consider a situation where  tasks spawn a large number of jobs (hundreds of thousands). In GridGain 4, we observed that the jobs got queued up in memory on the nodes potentially causing "out of memory" issues. We got around the issue by throttling job submission by creating a disk based queue and submitting the queued jobs as jobs finish.

Can (how?) GridGain 6 handle this situation and are there any specific recommendations? I see that there is a Streaming API available but can this handle our situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take advantage of *GridComputeTaskContinuousMapper* class which allows you to have a constant number of outstanding jobs within a task and then emit new jobs once other jobs complete.

Take a look at [ComputeContinuousMapperExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/compute/ComputeContinuousMapperExample.java) shipped with GridGain (also available on GitHub).

Comment: Ok, I will. That said , is GridComputeTaskContinuousMapper  In gridgain 6 subject to the same memory limitations that  I described in my initial post - or can the queued up jobs grow infinitely? I'll try and stress it , regardless

Comment: @VinayB GridComputeTaskContinuousMapper is invoked on the caller side, not on the receiver side. This way you can produce more jobs and submit them whenever some other jobs completed, and therefore not be exposed to memory limitations of having too many jobs.